# Unable to show last message from Firebase Realtime DataBase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to have conversation between two people in Firebase Realtime Database. That Chat goes fine no error but when i close the message activity to go to main activity my app crashes it even when i have a path it still shows me null_pointer exception.

Code for uploading message

```
private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message) {

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    hashMap.put("isseen",false);


    DatabaseReference Chatreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");

    String key = Chatreference.child(ChatKey).push().getKey();
    Chatreference.child(ChatKey).child(key).setValue(hashMap);
```

Code for seeing last message in adapter

```
private void lastMessage(final String userid, final TextView last_msg){
    theLastMessage = "default";
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats").child(ChatKey);//Line 133

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null) {
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        theLastMessage = chat.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }

            switch (theLastMessage){
                case  "default":
                    last_msg.setText("No Message");
                    break;

                default:
                    last_msg.setText(theLastMessage);
                    break;
            }

            theLastMessage = "default";
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Logcat

```
    2020-04-14 22:33:30.591 9241-9241/com.shivam.chatapp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shivam.chatapp2, PID: 9241
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:96)
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Adapters.UserAdapter.lastMessage(UserAdapter.java:133)
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Adapters.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:69)
        at com.shivam.chatapp2.Adapters.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:31)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1775)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1892)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
2020-04-14 22:33:30.592 9241-9241/com.shivam.chatapp2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Where are u going to the main activity? And which variable is null u can see the logcat it will tell u which line

Comment: @PeterHaddad i have updated the question hope it helps and also marked line 133

Comment: Chatkey is returning null

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yess but i can't figure out why

Comment: how did you get ChatKey

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir i just concatenated the Uid of current user and the user whom the current user is messaging.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        fuserkey=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

       // if (userid>fuserkey){}
        ChatKey=userid+fuserkey;

Comment: if (userid>fuserkey){ChatKey=userid+fuserkey; }  else ?   // Do you have else clause. Probably you don't have. How can it be ChatKey is null?

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir i don't have any other i was trying to add this clause to avoid duplication of data

Comment: have you tried this ->  else {.ChatKey= fuserkey + userid; }

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir i am trying this int i =(fuserkey).compareTo(userid);
         if (+i>=1){
             ChatKey=userid+fuserkey;
         }
         else if(+i<1) {
             ChatKey=userid+fuserkey;
         } but its creating two separate nodes what i want is storing all the chats between to users under there respective Chatkey

Comment: change -> else if(+i<1) { ChatKey=fuserkey + userid; }.

Comment: Now i can store all the messages under same Chatkey but error is still same   java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Comment: First create ChatKey after call lastMessage method

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir ChatKey is only generated when two users have interacted

Comment: So check chatkey is null before call lastMessage

Comment: Now its working instead of using Chatkey as public variable from Message Activity i now defined chat key again in user adapter now its not null

Comment: Happy coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier Chat key was returning null value because it was called after lastmessage, after defining Chatkey in userAdapter chatkey stopped returning null value .